# Office 365 Exchange SMTP intermittent authentication failure in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, office365

We have a number of C# (.net 4) apps that send email via our Office 365 Exchange account. This works absolutely fine 90% of the time. But sporadically we get the following error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM.

Here is the code:

```
private void SendEmail(string strTo, string strFrom, string strMessage, string strSubject, bool htmlFormat = true)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress mto = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(strTo);
        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress mfrom = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(strFrom);
        mail.Subject = strSubject;
        mail.From = mfrom;
        mail.To.Add(mto);
        mail.Body = strMessage;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = htmlFormat;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
        mailClient.Timeout = 1000000;
        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@emailaddress.com", "mypassword");
        mailClient.Send(mail);
    }
```

I've seen questions asked about this error message on here before, but I have not yet found any explanations as to why it might be happening only **intermittently**. The error message is confusing since I am not trying to send anonymously, and I am already using EnableSsl. (Note: if I remove the Credentials line or the EnableSSL line, then I get this error every time)

EDIT: As a test, I made a simple app that emails me 1 time per minute. I typically get between 12 and 25 successful emails before one blows up. Then it will go right back to normal for another 12-25, before blowing up again.

EDIT: Since the issue is so sporadic, and involves an error message returned from the 365 SMTP server, I don't really think its a problem with the code itself. Given that, I'm not sure if I've tagged the question properly, or if SO is even the best community for it. If any of you Stack Exchange veterans think this would be better placed in a different community, I am all ears. I'm a bit new here myself.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: I will post a method that you can use and or alter that works I just tested it

Comment: I'm also facing this intermittent problem.  I would say our mail service work 99% of the time then fails with the same error message "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM."
Did you find a solution to this old issue?

Comment: Not yet. I have a case open with Microsoft. They said others are experiencing the intermittent issue too. If we instead use a local IIS relay to communicate with 365, the error seems to go away. So that is a workaround, but I don't want to have to use a relay for every app. I am currently working on capturing SMTP logs in my .NET app to provide MS with more detail on what's going wrong exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a case with Microsoft 365 support on this, and they told me I was not the only one experiencing the issue. They had me try capturing SMTP logs when the issue occurs, but we never found much of anything very helpful. The MS tech also stated that he was going to try upgrading something on our mail server on the back end (not sure what exactly). After he did that the problem was still occurring but seemed less frequent.

Eventually it became less and less frequent and now I have not seen it occur in about 5 days. So, I don't know that this is from anything specific that my MS tech did, or just a larger problem eventually getting solved. But for now, the problem seems to have gone away, and not by changing anything on our end.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void SendEmail(string sTo, string subject, string body)
{
    var Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(Your EmailHost, Port))
    using (var message = new MailMessage()
    {
        From = new MailAddress(FromEmail),
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        message.To.Add(sTo);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailCredential"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"]);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(message);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MethodMan, it appears our code is much the same except for that you are including the `DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;` line. I could try adding that to mine and let it run for a while to see if it makes a difference. Testing is tricky as this issue happens very intermittently.

Comment: our code is a little different in the way that I create the mailmessage much cleaner in the way that I constructed it.. I hope this works for you. I use this all the time currently in all our production environments never had a failure yet.. `knock on wood` lol

Comment: `DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;` is the default, setting it does nothing.

Comment: @jstedfast it works with or without it.. I have just tested it.. [SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpdeliverymethod(v=vs.110).aspx) still default or not one must not always assume ...thanks

Comment: Normally I like to be explicit as well, but in this particular case, not much chance of SmtpClient ever defaulting to local delivery :)

Comment: it works regardless if it's there or commented out.. cheers...!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same sporadic behavior using your code. Just like with mine, it works fine 90% of the time, but every now and then I get that error message on the `client.Send(message)` line. Since its so intermittent, I don't think this is a problem with the code, but rather some quirk of 365 Exchange that I don't yet understand.

Answer (score 0):

- After adding SMTP details properly in your email application

  - You need to go to on the > Microsoft 365 admin center (https://admin.microsoft.com) > Active users
  - Select a user you wish to authenticate with the SMTP server
  - Select the Mail Tab (See Image 1)
  - Under Email apps, Select> Manage email apps
  - Make sure  that "Authenticated SMTP" checkbox is selected (See Image 2)
  - And save

  Your email should work after that.

**IMAGES EXAMPLES HERE**

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRDZa.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz6qA.png)